# Universal archive unpacker library

Tags: archive, unpack, compression

A lot of antiviruses can unpack most archives, found on users harddrives. They dissect `.zip`, `.rar`, `.chm`, `.exe`, `.msi` (and other installers) and a lot lot more. Also they can unpack an executable (get resources from them, unpack packed executable and unpack SFX archives).

For example, the popular old [russian antivirus "Drweb"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dr._Web) have support for many archive formats:

> Dr.Web knows many types of archives. At present they are:
>   ZIP, 7ZIP, ARJ, RAR, LHA, HA, GZIP, TAR, BZIP2, MS CAB, WISE, MSI, ISO, CPIO, RPM, DEB

Is there a library or utility which allows me to unpack most archives?

Is there a library to unpack an executables like it is done by antiviruses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An utility/library to unpack a lot of archives is [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/)

> Supported formats:
>
> Packing / unpacking: 7z, XZ, BZIP2, GZIP, TAR,
> ZIP and WIM
>
> Unpacking only: ARJ, CAB,
> CHM, CPIO, CramFS, DEB, DMG, FAT, HFS,
> ISO, LZH, LZMA, MBR, MSI, NSIS, NTFS,
> RAR, RPM, SquashFS, UDF, VHD, WIM, XAR
> and Z.

[UniExtract](http://www.legroom.net/software/uniextract) also supports the unpacking of executables.

> Universal Extractor is a program
> designed to decompress and extract
> files from any type of archive or
> installer, such as ZIP or RAR files,
> self-extracting EXE files, application
> installers, etc. It's able to support so
> many varied file formats by utilizing
> the many backend utilities listed in
> the credits at the bottom of the page.
>
> Please note that Universal Extractor
> is not intended to be a general
> purpose archiving program.  It cannot
> (and never will) create archives, and
> therefore cannot fully replace
> archivers such as 7-Zip or WinRAR.
> What it will do, however, is allow you
> to extract files from virtually any
> type of archive, regardless of source,
> file format, compression method, etc.
>
> The original motivation behind this
> project was to create an easy,
> convenient way to extract files from
> various types of installation packages
> without the need to remember arcane
> command line switches or track down
> separate utilities to handle the
> unpacking.  Over time, and with the
> encouragement of its many users and
> the fine folks over on the MSFN forum,
> it has evolved into a mature and very
> capable unarchiving utility that many,
> including myself, find indispensable.

Answer (score 2):

7zip is good but supports only two dozens of file formats:

> Packing / unpacking: 7z, XZ, BZIP2, GZIP, TAR, ZIP and WIM
>
> Unpacking only: ARJ, CAB, CHM, CPIO, CramFS, DEB, DMG, FAT, HFS, ISO, LZH, LZMA, MBR, MSI, NSIS, NTFS, RAR, RPM, SquashFS, UDF, VHD, WIM, XAR and Z.

Universal Unpacker supports more (and it uses good TrID  binary signature detector):

> .7z, .ace, .arc, .arj, .bin, .cue, .bz2, .tar, .cpio, .deb, .cdi, .b64, .uu, .uue, .xx, 
>   .xxe, .yenc, .ntx, .gz, .img, .cab, .1, .lib, .iso, .kgb, kge, .lzh, .lha, .lzma, .lzo, .Z, .tz, .lzx, .mht, .cab, .imf, .chm, .??_, .lit, .hlp .nbh, .nrg, .exe, .dbx, .pea, .rar, .rpm, .sis, .sit, .xz, .uha, UPX, .wim, .msm, .msi, .msp, .msu, .zip, .jar, .zoo

There is [PeaZIP open source archiver](http://peazip.sourceforge.net/peazip-free-archiver.html) (LGPL) with support of:

> Read (browse, extract, test): 7z, apk, bz, bz2, bzip2, tbz2, tbz, gz, tpz, tar, zip, zipx, z01, smzip, arj, cab, chm, chi, chq, chw, hxs, hxi, hxr, hxq, hxw, lit, cpio, deb, lzh, lha, rar, rpm, z, taz, tz, iso, jar, ear, war, lha, pet, pup, pak, pk3, pk4, slp, [Content], xpi, wim, u3p, lzma86, lzma, udf, xar, dmg, hfs, part1, split, swm, tpz, kmz, xz, txz, vhd, mslz, apm, mbr, fat, ntfs, exe, dll, sys, msi, msp, ods, ots, odm, oth, oxt, odb, odf, odg, otg, odp, otp, odt, ott, gnm, doc, dot, xls, xlt, ppt, pps, pot, docx, dotx, xlsx, xltx, swf, flv, quad, balz, zpaq, paq8f, paq8jd, paq8l, paq8o, lpaq1, lpaq5, lpaq8, ace, arc, wrc, 001, pea, cbz, cbr, cba, cb7, cbt (and more...)